# Word replacement not working in some areas

Tags: contacts, admin

I'm in Canada, and instead of County, we use "Province". I've set up a Word Replacement for "County" to change it to "Province", but when I edit a Contact, the label on the form still reads "County".

I'm running civiCRM 4.6.9 under Joomla 3.4.5

A short video walkthrough: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ok02KLEpYKM

Can anyone explain why this Word Replacement isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

Word replacement for County works on the demo - I renamed it to County/rename.

http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contact/add&reset=1&ct=Individual

State/Province is a default field, I'm not sure why you're not using that, instead of renaming. Look at your address settings, link on demo: http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/address&reset=1